# 2D Brouwer fixed point theorem

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Who was the first one to prove **Brouwer fixed point theorem** in plane? All I know that it was Piers Bohl who proved it in 3D case.

Comment: It's a not too hard consequence of some complex function theory, so it could have been 19th century. I cannot reach my books right now, I'll try and find it. Did you look in the Encyclopedia of the History of General Topology (which has at least 2 parts)?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma True. Since complex analysis proof uses Cauchy's theorem, it can be assumed that after Jordan curve theorem the 2D case was proved.

Comment: On page 115 of Jean Mawhin's ["*Poincaré's early use of Analysis situs in nonlinear differential equation: Variations around the theme of Kronecker's integral*"](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PHSC/PHSC_2000__4_1/PHSC_2000__4_1_103_0/PHSC_2000__4_1_103_0.pdf), he notes that Poincaré had sketched a correct argument for a result equivalent to the Brouwer fixed point theorem in 1884.  This equivalence was demonstrated by Carlo Miranda in 1940.